# How to fix 'PageHeader' error in ant.design

Tags: antd

I have followed the documentation (https://ant.design/components/page-header), but an error.

Module not found: Can't resolve 'antd/es/page-header'

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the Page Header component?

```
import { PageHeader } from 'antd';
```

Comment: Yes, it has already been done. This problem has been resolved, only with the antd version update. Thank you